# Kronecker product of selection matrix with itself

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

I have a selection matrix `W`. I need the kronecker of the transpose of this matrix with itself:

```
% Illustrative setup
n = 100;
ind = rand(1, n) > 0.5; 

% Current solution
W = sparse(eye(n));
W = W((ind==1),:);
kronWW = kron(W', W');
```

However, this seems to be quite inefficient since it's doing a lot of `1 * 1` operations. Since I know this is basically a fancy `repmat`, I'd like to see if the runtime improves by `repmat`-ing but I've so far been unable to think of a way to do this without the explicit loop over elements of `W` (which I've dismissed out of hand as likely slower).

Is there a way to conditionally replicate a matrix based on the logical input of another matrix that would replicate the kronecker product here?

Comment: Does the speed improve if you cast W to type `logical`? Then the multiplies could be replaced by ANDs, might be faster.

Comment: It does! For `n > 15` or so, there's big gains. At `n = 100` it's 2 orders of magnitude faster!